# Error calling container "xxxxxx": Error unmarshalling input on Redhat Business Central

Tags: java, drools, redhat-brms, redhat-bpm

I'm new in Redhat Business Central and exploring. I have created the application and deployed it successfully. I have a problem when I send a POST to the server.

I'm getting an error "Error unmarshalling input". I have attached the screen shoot of my objects and rule

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems you are missing the opening curly braces before 'commands' array.

Comment: the object looks like this   ```{

"commands":[
  {
    "insert":{
      "object":{
        "com.myspace.demo.Applicant":{
          "idType":01
        }
      }
    }
  },
  
  {
    "fire-all-rules":{
    }
  }
]
}``` the curl braces is there just that is missing from my screenshoot

Comment: Try adding "X-KIE-ContentType:JSON" in header. Through swagger you cant add additional headers so try executing it through REST clients like postman or through curl command from commandline.

Comment: @Abhijit Humbe I took your advice tried it on  postman and i'm still getting the same error

Comment: I'm a bit iffy on this unquoted '01' value. Is it supposed to be an octal? Numbers with leading zeroes are traditionally (and in Java) octals.

Comment: @mrobi if possible  share exception snip from server log

Answer (score 0):

Try by Adding `"lookup" : null,` in the starting of the request.
So now th request will look like

```
{
  "lookup" : null,
  "commands" : [
```

My Request was like this

```
{
  "lookup" : null,
  "commands" : [ 
    {
    "insert" : 
      {
          "out-identifier":"Name_of_container",
          "return-object":"true",
      "object" :{

          "class_name":
          {
              "obj1":"val1",
              "obj2":"val2",
          }
      }
      }
    },
    {
    "fire-all-rules" : {}
    } ]
}
```